# Using automator to apply javascript to local text files on computer

Tags: javascript, text, io, automator

Hi I wrote some javascript that I want to automatically apply on text files added to a folder on my computer, because I saw that you can use javascript in Automator.

Now I'm stuck but I feel this *should* be easy:

- I want Automator to pass text content from a .txt file as a `text` variable, so the javascript can apply the script I wrote with
- **or for automator to** pass on the text file's address as a variable to javascript so it can `readAsText()`
- Then I want the `newText` that the script creates, to pass it back to replace the original .txt file, and save and replace the original.

Is this possible?
I hope I didn't write the script for nothing. If anyone knows how to apply the javascript on local files, I'd super appreciate it!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple demonstration of how to use the **Run JavaScript** action in Automator to take a file or files as input, read their contents, manipulate it, then write it back to file.

This particular example indents the lines of a file by one tab stop:

[image: Screenshot of Automator workflow]

```
App = Application.currentApplication();
App.includeStandardAdditions = true;

function run(documents) {
        documents.forEach(filepath => App.write(
                App.read(filepath)
                   .split('\n')
                   .map(line=>"\t"+line)
                   .join('\n'),
                { 'to': filepath }
        ));

        return App.displayNotification(
                'Done', {
                        'withTitle' : 
                        'Indent Contents of File'
                }
        );
}
```